# In the dihedral group $D_{2m}$ for $m$ odd, does conjugation by $w_0$ exchange the simple reflections?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, reflection, coxeter-groups

Suppose you have a Coxeter group $W$ of type $I_2(m)$, the dihedral group.

If $m$ is odd, and $s_1$ and $s_2$ are the simple generators, $w_0$ the longest element, is it true that $w_0s_1w_0=s_2$ and, equivalently, $w_0s_2w_0=s_1$. And if $m$ is even, is it true that $w_0s_1w_0=s_1$, and $w_0s_2w_0=s_2$?

I know that when $W$ acts as reflections on a Euclidean space, $w_0$ is central when $m$ even, and acts as $-1$, and when $m$ is odd, $w_0$ is not central acts as the negative of the nontrivial automorphism of the Coxeter diagram, so I am wondering if there are similar things we can say when doing multiplication in the group $W$ itself, instead of viewing it as acting on some Euclidean space.

Comment: That action of $W$ on the Euclidean space is faithful, so any identity between elements of $W$ that holds in the action also holds in the group itself.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks. So if $m$ even, $w_0$ is central in $W$, settling the even case. If $m$ is odd, $w_0$ is not central in $W$, but since conjugation by $w_0$ preserves length, $w_0s_1w_0=s_i$ for $i=1,2$. But $i=2$ is the only option, otherwise $w_0$ would be central. Is this correct?

Comment: Sounds right! In this case it won't be too arduous to check that writing $w_0$ in terms of $s_1$ and $s_2$ either.